# Panel breaks on Safari IOS 7 scrolling page quickly

Tags: jquery-mobile

Using the panel widget I noticed that if you quickly scroll the page the panel breaks down and no longer works.

You can try this behavior on the demo site of [jQueryMobile 1.3.2](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/panels/).
I used Safari of an iPhone with IOS7, I don't know with other Android devices....

Has anyone noticed this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using:

```
data-swipe-close="false"
```

Obviously now you can't use swipe gesture to close panel.

Here the [discussion issue on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6148?source=cc).